# dotnet publish invokes unexpected call to Azure devops

Tags: c#, azure-devops

In response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557009/server-error-403-forbidden-on-blazor-server-app-published-to-linux-hosting) I am typing

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64
```

at the command line
To my surprise dotnet tries to invoke one of my Azure build pipelines

My screen shows the following

> C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\BlazorApp1>dotnet publish --runtime
> linux-x64 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Determining projects to restore... C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load
> the service index for source
> https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/blahblah/nuget/v3/index.json.
> [C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1.sln] C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Response
> status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
> [C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1.sln]

I don't use Azure Devops on this project, but I do for another project, and that pipeline started failing today.

Why is the project trying to call devops?

The Publish profile is set to a folder

[image: publish profile]

Comment: Your error explicitly tells you that you aren't authorized to `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/blahblah/nuget/v3/index.json` package source

Comment: It should not be trying to invoke devops so it does not matter whether I am authorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you have defined blahblah as a NuGet package source somewhere, typically in global NuGet configuration (typically `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`). It could also be that there is a NuGet config file somewhere in the parent folder to your project, as NuGet looks recursively for this file until it is found or until the root directory is hit. If the NuGet package source is defined in either of these, it will fail to restore packages as it can't know that the package(s) it seeks are not provided by that feed, thus restore fails.

Comment: I tried putting an edited Nuget.Config in the solutions folder but it made no difference.

Comment: IIRC the local nuget config is merged with the global, but replaces one higher up in the directory hierarchy.